# MySQL Reusing calculation in SELECT clause in a VIEW

Tags: mysql, select, view

I have an SQL query that has a simple date difference between `NOW()` and the creation date (is in the table). I need to reuse this again within the `SELECT` clause in a `VIEW`. Is this possible at all?

The query (note substitutions have been made from the original):

```
CREATE VIEW upcoming_events_view AS
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, `create_date`, NOW()) AS week_diff,
       (week_diff % week = 0) AS do_current_week
FROM event_repeats
```

Needless to say, this didn't work due to the `week_diff` being reused in the `SELECT` clause. As a normal `SELECT` query, I found variables worked; however, I can't use that in a `VIEW`:

```
SELECT *, @week_diff := TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, `create_date`, NOW()) AS week_diff,
       (@week_diff % week = 0) AS do_current_week
FROM event_repeats
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event_repeats` (
  `event_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `week` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=51 ;
```

What's the best way to do this (if any)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only do this in a view by repeating the expression.

```
CREATE VIEW upcoming_events_view AS
SELECT *, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, `create_date`, NOW()) AS week_diff,
       (TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, `create_date`, NOW()) % week = 0) AS do_current_week
  FROM event_repeats
```

The [`NOW()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) uses the time at the beginning of statement execution no matter how long the query takes to run, so you'd never get two different answers from `NOW()` in the same query.  The `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function's second invocation will probably not be optimized away by the optimizer, but this is a trivial calculation.  It benchmarks at 0.5 *microseconds* on an AMD Opteron 1GHz processor, so a million calls to that function takes half a second.

Since your `create_date` is a `DATE`, not a `DATETIME`, the `CURDATE()` function might be a more technically accurate choice, since the `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function first converts your dates to datetimes with an implicit 00:00:00 time element.

```
mysql> select TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),'2013-02-23'), TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,CURDATE(),'2013-02-23');
+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),'2013-02-23') | TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,CURDATE(),'2013-02-23') |
+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |                                          1 |
+----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The question is if you can reuse the calculation.  The fact that you can repeat it is not much of an answer.

Comment: The answer to "how do you do this?" is "you don't," ... or "no, you cannot reuse the calculation in a view, you have to repeat the expression."

Comment: Also thanks for the CURDATE() suggestion! Am using that now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another view to define the alias:

```
create view upcoming_events_view_base as
select  *
,       timestampdiff(week, `create_date`, now()) AS week_diff
from    event_repeats;

create view upcoming_events_view as
select  *
,       (week_diff % week = 0) AS do_current_week
from    upcoming_events_view_base;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3119/1)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Ok... how about another view?

Comment: Wouldn't that have a huge performance impact?

Comment: Views are very fast, I wouldn't expect a measurable difference.   Btw, where does the `week` in `(@week_diff % week = 0)` come from?

Comment: `week` is a column in the original table.